# No longer feel like playing chess?

Tags: psychology

Is it normal to no longer want to play chess? Or lose interest is probably a better way to put it. Is it temporary?

Comment: If western chess has lost its shine, maybe you'll like shogi or arimaa or go.

Comment: Do many chess players like go? I cannot speak for others, but go is interesting and is evidently hard to play well, yet it has never appealed to me as chess does.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's normal.

Can you identify why you lost interest? Are you losing too much or not showing improvement? re-evaluate your studies.

If you are winning too much (boredom), find better opposition.

“A bad day of Chess is better than any good day at work” - Anonymous